# Fail to start sppsvc service in Windows 11

Tags: windows, services

I bought a new laptop with an Nvidia GeForce 4070 GPU and an I7 12700 CPU. After installing Microsoft Office products, the service sppsvc stopped working as a result the Office apps raised the error "Office needs repair" and then after clicking on repair like online or offline, nothing happened.

I tried to restart the mentioned service and I encountered the following error:

> [image]

I decided to try anyway to start again that service and resolve the given error.

The summary of my attempts after many reinstalling of wnidows from scratch:

1. I disable Driver Signature Enforcement via recovery.
2. I changed the value of the key `InactivityShutdownDelayComputer` at `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform`.
3. I checked Task Scheduler to find a task relevant to it but there is nothing to do.
4. I installed the latest updates.

Any idea to solve this problem is appreciated do.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that this is the *cause* and not merely another *symptom*?

Comment: Due to suddenly Office says: needs to repair (license disappeared) and after a restart also sound not working and many apps disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, no, that all sounds like just a symptom of general corruption. The service handles Office licensing – it can't make *audio* disappear.

Comment: Currently I can't find, but a site said that sound troubles have direct relation with sppsvc service

Comment: @MR_ - That information was incorrect

Comment: You bought a new laptop. It has serious issues. Return it. If you try to fix something and make it worse, it might violate any warranty. Remove personal data before retruning it.

Comment: @MR_ Driver Signature Enforcementshould **_never_** be disabled - it's for driver devs only, If a driver's signature is corrupt, the driver should **_never_** be allowed to run because it's been tampered with or its download was corrupted. Did the Microsoft Office installer get downloaded directly from Microsoft's site? It sounds like the laptop is infected with malware and I'd treat it as such - exchanging it would be safest, else download a firmware update directly from the OEM's site, flash the motherboard's firmware, boot a Windows installUSB, wipe the drives, then reinstall Windows

Comment: The sppsvc service cannot have a bad digital signature. It seems like it was corrupted or replaced. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and also run a deep antivirus scan.

Answer (score 0):

The Software Protection service (`sppsvc`) cannot have a bad
digital signature. It's a major part of Windows and is defined as:

> Enables the download, installation and enforcement of digital licenses for Windows and Windows applications. If the service is disabled, the operating system and licensed applications may run in a notification mode. It is strongly recommended that you not disable the Software Protection service.

In sort, it's one of the first protections that a virus needs
to disable when it takes over a Windows system.

There is a very good chance that your computer is infected.

As a first measure, I suggest to test Windows integrity and
perhaps somewhat fix Windows by running the commands
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
followed by
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
and by doing deep antivirus scans by more than one vendor
(only download from the vendor's website).

If this is not enough, the re-installation of Windows will
be required.

For more information, see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)